# jQuery how to inject a new element right after each element of a selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery, sorry for asking this. I need to add a new `<div>` element after each element that have `.translatable` class, just when the page load and just for one time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Something like this would be perfect
   $(".translatable").appendRighAfter("<div></div>");

});
```

I know i should use `append()`, but i have no parent container to append to. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `after` function -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Something like this would be perfect
   $(".translatable").after("<div></div>");

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/after/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

You can pass a string to insert after your selection as well as a jQuery object.

If you want to insert before use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.translatable').after('</div>');
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9TJW/).

Answer (score 0):

You want [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("<div />").insertAfter(".translatable");
});
```

or [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".translatable").after("<div />");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `after` method which insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Something like this would be perfect
   $(".translatable").after("<div></div>");

});
```